# How to make an "atomic" block in VBA?

Tags: winapi, vba, excel

How can I make the following lines run as atomic operation:

```
Sheets("worksheet34").Select
Range("D15").Select
Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
SetCursorPos 200, 600 'set mouse position at 200, 600
Call mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0) 'click left mouse
Application.SendKeys ("R")
```

I would like to be sure that all the lines will be executed at the same order without a delay between each other.

The code above is my hack for going to a specific cell and choosing `REFRESH` on this cell.

[Win32: Atomic Execution of Code Block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288364/win32-atomic-execution-of-code-block)

[Synchronization Functions (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the code do?

Comment: I guess that Range("D15").Calculate does not work

Comment: @0x90 very interested to know in what context you are using this code snippet :) if you are care enough to share.

Comment: @bonCodigo what do you mean ?

Comment: @JohanLarsson you are right it didn't work

Comment: You stated "The code above is my hack for going to a specific cell and choosing REFRESH on this cell." Are you referring to sort of a self-cell refresh?

Comment: @bonCodigo it will refresh all the column though .... the same as if you would do it by yourself

Comment: to follow on from @JohanLarsson,  fully qualify the reference `sheets("worksheet34").range("D15").calculate`, and the recalculation should occur. @bonCodigo is trying to figure out why you need to recalculate a specific cell, to see if another method may work better for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You don't have that much control over Excel to guarantee it will be atomic, and Excel WILL be doing stuff in response to your messages, including a message pump which will be required for the popup menu.

The best way to find out how to do something in Excel VBA is to record a macro and look at the generated code.

In your specific case, the `Calculate()` method of a cell or range should refresh the value.